# Pass Parameter or Arguments to a Background task in Uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I am creating  a uwp app in which I want to take some data from user say from a textbox and then pass it to a background task. But when I am trying to add project reference to the background task I am getting a circular reference error. So is there any way to pass arguments maybe a overload of run function or anything else.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Romasz has explained it perfectly but in your case you can get the user data from the textbox by doing these steps:

1.Declare this in MainPage.xaml.cs(or your xaml page)

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings.Values["user"] = User.Text;
```

2.Now get the data in BackgroundTask.cs using these

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
string user = localSettings.Values["user"].ToString();
```

Here the variable user has the texbox data you wanted from the mainpage.

Note:I have assumed that you have named your textbox "User"

Comment: Hi! How to access SQLITE database from background task? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct way to do what you want, each process (for example *BTask* and *UI*) has its own memory and it cannot be accessed just like that.

You will need some kind of a broker for this purpose - for short communication I think you can use [LocalSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx), which should work fine - though in case of complex objects you may need to serialize them first. For more advanced communication you may also think of using a file in *LocalFolder* or other place that is accessible for all processes.

In some cases there may be a problem of synchronization of processes (or accessing shared resources, like files) - for this, there are designed objects for global synchronization, eg. *Mutex*, *EventWaitHanle*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation

Comment: Hi! How to access SQLITE database from background task? Thanks!