# uwp background task ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTriggerDetail toast arguments toast id or group

Tags: uwp, background-task

is there anyway to pass arguments to the background task that is triggered when a toast is removed. with ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTriggerDetail at the moment all it provides is the changetype.

also I would like to know how take action when the toast removed has a specific id or group

i.e I would like to pass a similar query string that I pass when using toastnotificationactiontrigger.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot pass parameters to background task. It's a separate process to control all registered background task.

Answer (score 0):

> is there anyway to pass arguments to the background task that is triggered when a toast is removed

For this question, there is no direct way to do that, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40524489/5254458)

As we know, the [`ToastNotificationHistory.GetHistory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationHistory#Windows_UI_Notifications_ToastNotificationHistory_GetHistory) method provides the capability to get notification history. We will get a collection of [`ToastNotification class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification). There is a **prerelease** property named [Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification#Windows_UI_Notifications_ToastNotification_Data):

***Attention: Some information relates to pre-released product which may be substantially modified before it’s commercially released. Microsoft makes no warranties, express or implied, with respect to the information provided here.***

> Prerelease. Gets or sets additional information about the status of
>   the toast notification.
>
> Property Value: NotificationData
>
> An object that provides additional information about the status of the
>   toast notification, such as the progress of the action described by
>   the notification.

Check out [`NotificationData Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.notificationdata)

---

> also I would like to know how take action when the toast removed has a specific id or group

There will be a **prerelease** property named [`CollectionId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationhistorychangedtriggerdetail#Windows_UI_Notifications_ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTriggerDetail_CollectionId) inside `ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTriggerDetail` Class

***Attention: Some information relates to pre-released product which may be substantially modified before it’s commercially released. Microsoft makes no warranties, express or implied, with respect to the information provided here.***

> Prerelease. Gets the ID of the notification group to which the
>   notification that caused the change trigger belongs.

**Welcome to join [Windows insider](https://insider.windows.com) and try the latest insider preview SDK.**